# .NET 7: Running/Debugging Azure Function locally -as an isolated process- from Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, xunit

I've created an AZ function project with the following -very simple- Program.cs:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .Build();

host.Run();

public partial class Program { }
```

And the next -dummy- function:

```
[Function("RabbitMQFunction")]
    public void Run
    (
        [RabbitMQTrigger("EmailQueue", ConnectionStringSetting = "xxx:xxx:services:infraestructure:emailservice:rabbitmq")] string item,
        FunctionContext context)
    {
        var logger2 = context.GetLogger("RabbitMQFunction");
        logger2.LogInformation($"Output message created at {DateTime.Now}");
    }
```

local.settings.json:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "xxx:xxx:services:infraestructure:emailservice:rabbitmq": "connection_string"
    },
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
    }
}
```

host.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Properties > launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "xxx_xxx_Services_Infrastructure_EmailService": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "--port 7246",
      "launchBrowser": false
    }
  }
}
```

I can run the function with no problems with func start from the command line (I already have Azure Functions Core Tools installed), but when I try to run/debug the function **from vscode**, the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'The gRPC channel URI 'http://:63205' could not be parsed.'
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.GrpcServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c.<AddGrpc>b__1_1(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at ...
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Select "Initialize Project for Use with VS Code..." under AZURE -> WORKSPACE -> Local Project or by using the command palette (Shift+Cmd+P on Mac, Shift+Ctrl+P on Windows) and executing the command Azure Functions: Initialize Project for Use with VS Code…

This will "Adds the required Visual Studio Code project files to an existing Functions project. Use this command to work with a project that you created by using Core Tools."

Answer (score 0):

Install the `Azure Functions` extension, and as soon as it is done, it will detect the azure functions in your solution and allow you to configure them automatically for VS Code.